# (Autocad) How to draw this line (pic included)

Tags: autocad

How do you draw this kind of line that ends with fully filled  2 black circles ?

[image]

Comment: you're probably talking about Linetypes, which can be done via API or via UI, what's your question? https://knowledge.autodesk.com/support/autocad/learn-explore/caas/CloudHelp/cloudhelp/2016/ENU/AutoCAD-Core/files/GUID-20B4D4B3-1220-426A-847B-5BBE36EC6FDF-htm.html

Comment: In fact question is not so easy.Using linetypes You can create line with black circles distributed with specified step, like every 1 unit (e.g. meter), but linetype with circles in endings or vertexes of polyline would be very usefull.